# Event get String from 2 buttons

Tags: java, android

I am using an Adapter to generate buttons in a GridView.

Using an OnClickListener, whenever I click a button from the GridView, it is possible to get the String of the button in a variable. However, I want to click a button, store its text in a variable, then click  a different button, store its text in another variable so later I can compare the two texts. How could I do that?

gI'm using OnClickListener, therefore my previous implementation for one button was the following:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
Button b = (Button)v;
String text = b.getText.toString();
```

With this approach, I can only get and store text from first button clicked, unless I store all the values in an array.

Comment: what does *the same event* mean?

Comment: I have an OnItemClick event, therefore if I want to get the text of a button I do:Button b = (Button)view; String poop = b.getText().toString(). But I would like to get the String from 2 buttons, meaning 2 items clicked in the GridView

Comment: Instead of using comments, clarify your question in your...question. And add relevant code there

Comment: @azurefrog of course the event is fired when clicking a button. But my question is: Click one button -> Event is fired -> Store text from button. So far so good. But I would like, another sequence, meaning storing in a variable the first text of the first button, then storing in a variable the second text of the second button clicked. Understandable?

Answer (score 0):

Please you can share your code to turn the things more comprehensible? Edit your question please... Anyways:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Button button1;
    private Button button2;
    private String butString, butString2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                butString = (String) button1.getText();
            }
        });
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                butString2 = (String) button1.getText();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

After that you can compare the two strings.

Comment: Since I'm using adapter for my GridView, this won't actually help me much :) 

There's not much code I can add, since I think I was explicit enough in my question: Adapter, GridView, generating buttons :) But thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

Ok so from what I can understand, you want to compare the strings of the two items in a grid view. If this is what you want, heres how I would do it(just a psuedocode):

```
String mValue1, mValue2;
boolean isOneClicked = false;

onItemClickedListener(item, position){
if(!isOneClicked){
  mValue1 = item.stringValue;
  isOneClicked = true;
}
else{
  mValue2 = item.stringValue;
  //do whatever you want here
  //Reset when done
  mValue1 = "";
  mValue2 = "";
  isOneClicked = false;
}
}
```

Comment: good idea, the problem is I'm using OnClickListener, therefore my previous implementation for one button was the following:
public void onClick(View v) {
Button b = (Button)v;
String text = b.getText.toString();

With this approach, I can only get and store text from first button clicked, unless I store all the values in an array.

Comment: you know how I could create an object of type Button for every reading?